# Django social with apple oauth sends final redirect without cookies

Tags: django, cookies, oauth, django-socialauth, apple-id

We are trying to get apple oauth working for a web app with a django backend using django-social. The initial login request sets a sessionid cookie but the final auth/complete request doesn't send any of the browser's cookies.  No errors in the console and our testing server uses ssl. The redirect_uri is correct, it's just missing it's cookies.

Settings in django we have tried:

```py
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
    SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = "Lax"
    SOCIAL_AUTH_APPLE_ID_CLIENT = '<our_website_name>'  # Your client_id com.application.your, aka "Service ID"
    SOCIAL_AUTH_APPLE_ID_TEAM = '<our_id>'  # Your Team ID, ie K2232113
    SOCIAL_AUTH_APPLE_ID_KEY = values.SecretValue()  # Your Key ID, ie Y2P99J3N81K
    SOCIAL_AUTH_APPLE_ID_SECRET_B64 = values.SecretValue()
    SOCIAL_AUTH_APPLE_ID_SCOPE = ['email', 'name']
    SOCIAL_AUTH_APPLE_ID_EMAIL_AS_USERNAME = True  # If you want to use email as username
    USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
    SOCIAL_AUTH_REDIRECT_IS_HTTPS = True

    @property
    def SOCIAL_AUTH_APPLE_ID_SECRET(self):
        return base64.b64decode(self.SOCIAL_AUTH_APPLE_ID_SECRET_B64


    AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        "rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication",
        "social_core.backends.open_id.OpenIdAuth",  # for Google authentication
        "social_core.backends.google.GoogleOpenId",  # for Google authentication
        "social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2",  # for Google authentication
        "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
        'social_core.backends.apple.AppleIdAuth', # Apple oauth
    )
```

This results in the following error:

```
[04/May/2020 22:18:39] "GET /auth/login/apple-id/ HTTP/1.0" 302 0
Internal Server Error: /auth/complete/apple-id/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/social_django/utils.py", line 49, in wrapper
    return func(request, backend, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/social_django/views.py", line 31, in complete
    return do_complete(request.backend, _do_login, user=request.user,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/social_core/actions.py", line 45, in do_complete
    user = backend.complete(user=user, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/social_core/backends/base.py", line 40, in complete
    return self.auth_complete(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/social_core/utils.py", line 251, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/social_core/backends/oauth.py", line 388, in auth_complete
    state = self.validate_state()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/social_core/backends/oauth.py", line 90, in validate_state
    raise AuthStateMissing(self, 'state')
social_core.exceptions.AuthStateMissing: Session value state missing.
[04/May/2020 22:18:53] "POST /auth/complete/apple-id/ HTTP/1.0" 500 102779
```

Is this a django setting or a django-social setting that we missed?
Can anyone help us? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tested without adblocker and in all browsers? Just to be sure its not something to do with those

Comment: Have you tried: `SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None` ? https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/issues/250#issuecomment-436832460